# Qt Application showing back content

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I'm developing an Qt Quick Application with C++ and QML.

The mainwindow doesn't show the content, and shows part of the back window content(the QT IDE)
The problem is when running the project in Debug/Release(both) mode. Running the binary from the project folder works. But I need to test it from debug mode.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (Xfce).

How can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: be more specific, whats your particular problem ?

Comment: Could you add the desktop you are using? Looks like Gnome, right?

Comment: @SimonWarta it's xcfe.

Comment: Why is your main windows a .cpp/.h file when you are using Qt Quick? Tell us a bit more about your application structure.

Comment: I think that the problem might be about a configuration of QT IDE,  because it happens with every UI project.  The cpp/h is just an class that contains the UI for showing, nothing important.

Comment: Since Qt Quick is rendered entirely different than Qt Widgets, that is essential information you should provide as detailed as possible if you want this to be understood and fixed.

Comment: It also happens when I open the QT IDE. I don't see the dashboard or welcome page.  It just shows the window that is back as an frozen image.  Thanks

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your dashboard view with no Qt app running above it?

Comment: I think this Error related to Ubuntu 14. I am using same ubuntu and every time i run QtCreator, IDE run and show welcome mode, in this mode background of IDE is my desktop.
if I switch mode only one time, this error does not happend any more.

Comment: The mainwindow doesn't show the content, and shows part of the back window content -- check your OpenGL driver, that might be the main issue